# Preventing Telegram Link Previews using a URL redirect site

Tags: url, redirect, telegram, telegram-bot, url-parameters

Currently I have a telegram bot that outputs a URL, but everytime the bot sends a URL telegram creates a link preview. One solution I came up with was pass this URL through a URL redirect service or website to break the link preview. Is there a url redirect service where I can append a URL parameter where it will redirect to that site?

I can code up my own php script that parses the URL parameter, but if a service already exists I rather use that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

-- Edit: From December 29, 2023 update, to disable previews the option are: --

```
link_preview_options: {
    is_disabled: true,
},
```

---

You can set `disable_web_page_preview` attribute to true when using `sendMessage` method.

It will disable link previews for links in this message.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

Comment: When using ```api.telegram.org/botBOTKEY/sendMessage``` you can even use this as an url parameter (```&disable_web_page_preview=true``` ). It just worked for me today.